# PHP Session variable isset(..)=1 after session_start()

Tags: php, session, apache2, session-variables

I guess I am not understanding the scope of session variables, or the session itself, in PHP, hence this question:

This is my code

```
  if(session_id()!=""){
  echo "Getting rid of session"."</br>";
  session_destroy();
 }
 echo "Before session_start(): ".isset($_SESSION["first_date_of_week"])."</br>";
 session_start();
 echo "After session_start(): ".isset($_SESSION["first_date_of_week"])." ".$_SESSION["first_date_of_week"]->format("Y-m-d")."</br>";
```

The output is:

```
Before session_start():
After session_start(): 1 2011-01-09
```

How come that when doing the isset(..) on the session variable it is set directly after starting the session, even though I haven't even used it or set it yet? It does, however, still have the same value as before.

Also, session_id()="" since the if-clause is never triggered. I never kill the session, how come it is set to ""? I.e. I refresh the page and expects the session to still be alive.

Using the isset(..) function is then pretty useless testing if it has been set already...

Thanks in advance!

/Niklas

Comment: A hint: `!session_id()==""` is evaluated as `(!session_id()) == ""` not what you (might?) had in mind `!(session_id() == "")`. Use the `!=` operator...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the code:

1. The test `!session_id()==""` is wrong because `!` has a higher precedence than `==`. It should be written as `session_id() != ""`. Due to implicit conversions it should work correctly, but I can't say it's anything else than a bug.
2. `session_destroy` only works if called *after* `session_start`.

Now, here's what happens exactly:

1. You test for an active session. Since there's none, the test fails and `session_destroy` is never called (it would do nothing even if it were called).
2. You test for the existence of `$_SESSION["first_date_of_week"]`. Since there's no active session, `isset` return false.
3. You start the session. `$_SESSION["first_date_of_week"]` now becomes available, *but only because you had set it on some earlier session, in code that you don't show*.

Try this code to get a better handle on what's going on:

```
$logout = true; // play with this
session_start();
if ($logout) {
    session_destroy();
    echo "Logged out.";
    die;
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
}
else {
    ++$_SESSION['counter'];
}

echo "The counter value is ".$_SESSION['counter'];
die;
```

Comment: As Nicsoft noted session_destroy is never called.

Comment: But if it is the same page loaded twice and I want to start a new session each time that page (kind of an entry page) is loaded, shouldn't the session be alive and session_id=="" be false if not destroying the session elsewhere? I did update to "if(session_id()!="")..." but no change in behaviour. True, I did sest it in an earlier session.

Comment: @Nicsoft: the session will **not** be "alive" if you don't call `session_start` first. Notice that in my example I 'm doing this always, both when I want to log out and when I don't.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Your comment together with Nannes helped me, session_start is not starting a new session, but I thought it actually did... Adding the session_start before the if-clause fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that session_start doesn't start a *new* session, just starts "the session". So if you've set something (and you haven't destoryed it, see @Jon 's answer), then you'll get your session back :)

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start();
if(isset(session_id())) {
    session_destroy();
}
$_SESSION['data'] = "something";
```